# ExpandableListView only showing one parent

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, expandablelistview

Among other `View`s, I am trying to programmatically add an `ExpandableListView` to a `LinearLayout`. To do this, I am using the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`. There are supposed to be ten parent elements, each with a single child element. It is encased in the `onPostExecute` of an `AsyncTask`, if that matters. Here is the java:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> parentList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> childList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int k = 0 ; k < 10 ; k++)
{
    HashMap<String,String> parentMap = new HashMap<>();
    parentMap.put("item", i + ":" + k + "source");
    parentList.add(parentMap);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> childItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String,String> childMap = new HashMap<>();
    childMap.put("item", i + ":" + k + "data");
    childItemList.add(childMap);
    childList.add(childItemList);
}

/* Build expandable list */
SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
        details,

        parentList,
        R.layout.expandable_parent,
        new String[] {"item"},
        new int[] {R.id.expandable_parent},

        childList,
        R.layout.expandable_child,
        new String[] {"item"},
        new int[] {R.id.expandable_child}
);
ExpandableListView info = new ExpandableListView(details);
info.setAdapter(adapter);
layout.addView(info);
```

This is expandable_parent.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/expandable_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And expandable_child.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/expandable_child"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There may be a few mistakes in there, as I just took a simplified version of the Java. But the problem is that when it is run, only the first parent element shows up. I click on it and the image on the left flips, indicating that the group was opened, but no child elements are displayed. What's the problem?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that the `ExpandableListView` is being added to a `LinearView` that is inside a `ScrollView`. Are you not allowed to have an `ExpandableListView` in a `ScrollView`?

Comment: Yep that was the problem. Nevermind then.